# How can I solve this GParted problem?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk

Here I don't know what should I do. Is it impossible to resize this partition?

[image]

Comment: As the error says, unmount the partition and then try to resize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: How I should unmount the partition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that you are trying to work on the disk and on the partition layout from within the running Ubuntu operating system and this is not recommend, also creating a new partition table is not possible.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media and select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.
On the Live desktop open GParted, right-click the swap partition and click swapoff.

Now you can create a new partition table. But is this what you really want to do ?
When you create a new partition table, the whole disk will be erased completely.

Maybe you just want to resize partitions ?
Learn more here -> [How to prepare a disk ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu/743098#743098)

Comment: Is it impossible to edit partition after completing installation ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmad : No it is not impossible - you just have to do it from a Live media, where all partitions are not mounted ... but be careful when you edit partitions and backup the data you want to keep before ... :)